# PHP email header FROM field not displaying correctly

Tags: php, email

I need help getting the FROM field in the email to be a specific email address.  As of now it is coming out something like this.  Looks like its grabbing info off my hosting companies server.

ipw.xxxxxxxxx@boscustweb1302.eigbox.net

All other features of email work great.  My `$headers` are as follows:

```
$to = $email;
$subject = "ORDER # $tranid";
$headers = "From: info@xxxxxx.com";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
```

PHP manual sugest this.  Which is pretty much what I am doing, I think.

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
   'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

They do use implode, but I don't think I need it the way I have mine setup:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Tried this with no success:

```
$to = $email;
$subject = "ORDER # $tranid";
$headers .= "From: info@xxxxxx.com";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
```

Comment: You are overwriting every header. You need `.=` on every assignment after the first. So your header is only `Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`.

Comment: ...and `implode` works with arrays, using an array would be cleaner.

Comment: umm I just tried this 
 $headers .= 'From: info@stoneparkprod.com' . "\r\n" .
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0";
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"; But no different.  But it does make the email NOT see my HTML correctly

Comment: And what happened? Your lines still need to end with semicolons.

Comment: I agree with using an array, but would that fix my problem?

Comment: It should, use the array for each header then implode with new lines for glue.

Comment: I just edited bottom of post. This is what you are saying?  But this actually makes it so the email doesn't even go through.  Is my code bad?

Comment: You need new lines, that isn't using the array apporach.

Comment: I recommend to use a well tested library like phpmailer or something like this.

Comment: Ok I have made some progress doing an array like you sugested gets me the FROM correct, but it destroys my HTML, here is my array:   $headers = 'From: info@xxxxxx.com';
    'MIME-Version: 1.0';
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

Comment: Ok I got It - Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer with the help of **@chris85**

```
$headers = "From: info@xxxxx.com\r\n". 
           "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" . 
           "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

Keeps HTML format in tack and shows FROM field correctly.